# Compute weight value based on other attributes?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I have a shapefile with multiple attributes.  I would like to give a "weight" for each value of those attributes in order to get an "ordering" of my features.

My shapefile represents roads, for each road I have informations like, speed limit (30, 50, 70, etc.); condition of the road (good, bad, average, etc.); light (good, average, bad) etc.

My intention is to give to each value a "weight" -> if the speed limit is 70 then value 3, if the speed limit is 30 then value 1 / If the light is good value 1 and if the light is bad value 3 / etc.

At the end I would like a column with the total of "points" each segment of road get.

Can I do this with the field calculator, or do I need SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the field calculator using

```
CASE WHEN condition THEN result END
```

but it would be a tedious process if you have lots of fields with lots of possible combinations. You would have to write a line for each combination, which can be potentially error-prone.

As an example:

```
CASE 
WHEN "speed" = 30 AND "Light" = 'Bad' THEN 4 
WHEN "speed" = 30 AND "Light" = 'Good' THEN 2
END
```

Perhaps an easier way is to create a weight field for each initial field and eventually just one field that would sum up all the weight fields.

Comment: I will try the multiple CASE WHEN solution. I used this function in the past but didn't know you can use it more than one time. Thanks